# Change or re-ask Facebook Publish Actions Visibility - Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-group

I have created an app that allows a user to post to a group at a certain time. I ran into the issue that if the user denied the permission initially, I'd have to re-ask them for it, no problem.

The problem is that I cannot post to a Facebook group unless publish_actions visibility is set to public, I get the same oauth 200 error if they didn't grant me publish_actions in the first place. I thought re-asking for publish actions would fix this, but when I bring up the login dialog re-asking, it closes immediately, I would presume because it realizes the user already granted the permissions I am asking for.

Is there any way I can prompt the user to change the app visibility within the app or must they go to their settings to change that -- which would really suck.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe this is possible through the API

Comment: Well.. damn.. thanks for the reply anyways!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way whatsoever to either know the visibility or re-request it. But what you can do is revoke the permission via API and re-request it.
You can use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking to revoke the permission & re-request like you did the first time.